# How far does the mother have to fly away to fulfill the mitzva of Shiluach Haken?

Tags: halacha, shiluach-haken

Does the mother bird need to actually go away from the area of the nest or as long as it is removed from the nest it's fine even if it is in the immediate vicinity or right next to it.

Comment: related: [How must one send away the mother bird?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101210/11501)

Answer (score 3):

**[Chulin 141b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=141b&format=pdf)**

> עד כמה משלחה אמר רב יהודה כדי שתצא מתחת ידו
>
> How far must he let it go? — Rab Judah said, until it is out of his reach.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Chullin.pdf))

This is codified in [Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 292:4](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6809).

Comment: That is clearly addressing the question but I think a more exact translation would be "until she leaves his grasp" which leaves a little room for clarification when one did not actually grasp and release the bird (as the Gemara there discusses there) and instead resorted to other means of moving it such as using a stick or scaring it away. In such a scenario, when is it considered "leaving his grasp"?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Alex's answer, it is also worth noting the [Chazon Ish on YD siman 175, os beis](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14334&st=&pgnum=412&hilite=) who qualifies the Gemara in Chullin to mean that the mother bird is far enough that he wouldn't be able to grab her if he tried, i.e. beyond his reach.

> כדי שתצא מתחת ידו היינו מרשותו שאם יחפוץ לתופשה לא יוכל
>
> "Until it is out of his reach" - this means from his position, if he wanted to grab her, he wouldn't be able to.